# Java ExecuteUpdate failing and not throwing exception

Tags: java, database-connection

Today I encountered this case: The program starts, works as usual, displays message that the data has been entered in the database correctly, but it didn't do it. I ran the script again and it worked fine, but the interesting thing is that it didn't throw an exception although it failed to insert the data.

Is there a case where Statement.executeUpdate(insertQuery) can fail without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although a failure cannot happen without throwing an exception, a command can complete with the effect that does not match your expectations, but without actually failing.

For example, if you issue a command to update a row, but the ID that you have specified for the update does not exist in the table, the command will technically succeed, but from your point of view the update would fail, because no rows were changed:

```
PreparedStatement upd = con.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE mytable SET complete=1 WHERE id=?"
);
upd.setInt(1, 12345); // If 12345 does not exist...
upd.executeUpdate();  // ...this update does not change anything
```

To detect situations like that you can check how many rows a command has updated, and do something when the number of updates is zero:

```
int changed = upd.executeUpdate();
if (changed != 1) {
    // Something didn't go according to our expectations
}
```

Comment: My problem came in an INSERT query, but I think I get what you mean. Thank you.